# Am I forced to use mirroring of entities by domain-driven design in WASM?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, domain-driven-design, webassembly

I'm working on Blazor with server side and WASM.

In DDD (Domain Driven Design), all entities are stored in domain layer (Core) project where services (all business logic) are placed, too.

But since WASM is executed on the client, any code there can be decompiled, meaning that wasm can't have any reference to Core. It's enforcing me to mirror all domain entities with duplicated entities and DTOs which is not the best solutions since we will have two identical classes and when changing one I need to keep in mind to modify all mirroring entities too.

They do not relate tight, so Visual Studio will not throw compilation error if I will forget to modify mirroring entity. For me, it looks like a nightmare, but I do not understand how architecture must look like for Wasm without breaking DDD rules OR leave critical security vulnerabilities in my program.

Comment: "But since WASM is executed on the client, any code there can be decompiled, meaning that wasm can't have any reference to Core".  [Polite] Why not?  Exposing entities shouldn't  leave critical security vulnerabilities`.   If you have lots of security critical stuff in your code domain, then WASM probably isn't the right solution for you.  You're front end is just a UI, which is basically what Server is.

Comment: Because decompiled code mean that you exposed your business logic, which can now be stolen or even worse, potential hacker can see your guts and find critical vulnerabilities in your system, including ciphers, salts, tokens, in the end even just a database connection string hacker also can see used practice and can use this information to further breakthrough attacks. So that's why I think it's extremely dangerous to expose your inner domain layers to the outside.

Comment: I use wasm because app have autonomous mode when wasm working only with cached data without internet connection, I think about maui too instead of Wasm, but problem will stay sane.

Comment: I agree with all you say, So don't use the WASM model.  I don't in the applications I write for that very reason.  You can in theory segregate out all the ciphers/salts/tokens into a server side core separate from the shared core, and Db Connections are infrastructure domain, which is pure server side.  But it's painful.

Comment: You need to bend your design.   Anaemic data objects that your presentation layer uses in a shared core domain,  business logic in a server side core domain. All your critical stuff behind API calls.  It's all about where you draw the client side/ server side line in the sand!

Comment: @IgorMarkiv I didn't use WASM in practice, If you use view models to communicate with the UI and convert view models to DTOs of your application layer (commands if you applied CQS or CQRS) and complete a scenario, does it reveal your domain layer?

Comment: No, I do not use view models since I do not have views, wasm is single page application and system communicate using DTOs via https/web sockets(SignalR), but it's not as convenient as if I used the domain models directly in wasm since DTOs  in fact in 90% cases just little simplified domain entities in Anaemic data objects form.